# Cannot find module "@src/styles.scss"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I import the style file in my project like this:

```
import styles from '@src/styles.scss';
```

The `tsconfig.json` file contains:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
},
"include": ["src"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"],
"compileOnSave": false
}
```

But my Visual Studio Code is throwing error `Cannot find module "@src/styles.scss"`. Although the assembly of the project occurs **without errors**. The `styles.scss` file does exist and is located in the `src` folder.

*In the project I use webpack 5 and I have already specified aliases in its config.*

Can you please tell me how to solve this **visual** problem?

Comment: r u triyng to import scss in javascript file? if yes, can u tell me where ur javascript file is located?

Comment: Can you provide an overview of your folder structure?

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas Folder structure: [link](https://imgur.com/SQFjXGZ)

Comment: @mmh4all I'm using Typescript along with React and i import in the `Home.tsx` file, which is located in the `src/components` folder

Comment: just use it like so import './styles.scss';

Comment: It happens only with `scss` files or also with `tsx` ?

Comment: @Amryasser When I use this, the problem is still there

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas This problem doesn't exist when I try to include `.tsx` files

Comment: Neither when using path aliases, like `@src/Layout` ?

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas All my modules are stored in the `src/components` folder. The import takes place in the `src/components/Home.tsx` file. The `styles.scss` file is located in the `src` folder. In the same folder, I created an empty `test.tsx` module, imported (`import styles from '@src/test'`) in the `src/components/Home.tsx` file - there are no errors.

However, if I import the `styles.scss` file, then there is an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days of searching for a solution, I still found it! The whole problem is that `typescript` only accepts files with `.js(x)/.ts(x)` extensions as modules.

Therefore, we need to manually specify that files with the `.scss` extension are **also modules**.

Create a `typings` folder in the root of the project. In this folder, create a `declarations.d.ts` file with the contents:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}
```

Now in the `tsconfig.json` file, add the `typings` folder:

```
{
  ...
  "include": ["typings", "src"],
}
```

I hope my answer saves someone time!

Comment: nice work, there are a few answers to this question elsewhere, which don't work, your solution has worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following our chat, I think that the reason `IntelliSense` is not working is that typescript `paths` look for `.js(x)/.ts(x)` extensions (which is not the case of `.scss`). The reason it works at build time is that `webpack` is taking care of it.

I recommend using a solution like [module-alias](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias) to get rid of this warning on VSCode.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me. The error still remains :(